# JS - using for loop to copy array properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to learn JS by working out the problems in Flanagan, JS: The Definitive Guide.  I would appreciate it if somebody pointed out the errors in my code.  The goal is to create a new array b with identical properties to array a.  There are two main results I don't understand:

- Array b ends up with length 4.  Shouldn't it have length 3 like array a?
- b[0] returns undefined.

This is my code:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++);
b[i] = a[i];
alert(b[0]);

var equalArrays = function (a,b) {
    if (a.length !== b.length) return false;
    if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
    else return true;
    };
alert (equalArrays(a,b));
```

Comment: As a note, in this very simple example you could just do `var b=a.slice();`

Comment: Funny thing is that [within 20 seconds of each other](http://i.imgur.com/tctQ0oi.png), 4 answers came in :P

Comment: Also note, be careful with such simple checks as your `equalArrays` as `var c = []; c[2] = 3;` would be `true`

Comment: The reason `b.length` is 4 is because at the loop end `i` is 4. so you are setting `b[4]=undefined` (see above to help understand, sparse arrays). Of course the exception to this rule is IE<9. See answers below as to why `b[0]` is undefined (semicolon);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your forloop never runs - you're placing a semicolon (`;`) right after the conditions for the loop, so it never recognises the line of `b[i] = a[i];` as part of the forloop.

To fix this, simply remove the semicolon:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    b[i] = a[i];
alert(b[0]);
```

You can also, to make it a bit clearer, add curly brackets around the contents of the loop. That would make it a lot harder to make mistakes like this one. The code for the forloop would then be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b[i] = a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++);
b[i] = a[i];
```

Semicolon screws it up. It's better to use `{}` for readability as well.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b[i] = a[i];
}
```

Comment: Yes, clarity is the essence of any language IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `;` at the end of your for loop so it only increments `i` to 4.

Then on the next line you assign `b[4] = a[4]` which explains both your issues (`b[0]` being `undefined` and `b`'s length of 4). Simply remove that `;`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    b[i] = a[i];
```

Auto-indentation in an IDE or wrapping your for body in `{ ... }` helps to notice these kinds of errors.

Comment: indentation doesn't help to find semicolons that shouldn't be there, does it?

Comment: @Joeytje50 It sure does. The `b[i] = a[i];` line would have been indented by an IDE if there was no `;` on the `for` line.

Comment: If you don't have an IDE that tries to be helpful and auto-indent your code for you, you can see where the semicolons were intended to be.  If you do have such an IDE, you'll see what the parser thinks you meant.

Comment: @Vache ah so your suggestion is to use an IDE, not to use indentation.

Comment: @Joeytje50 To use the auto-indent feature within an IDE, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

change your for loop to

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    b[i] = a[i];
```

(skip the ; at the end of "for line").

Or to make it even more clear by replacing the for loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    b[i] = a[i];
}
```

This actually means the same but might be easier to understand that the code part in brackets get executed with every for loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

While a `for` statement can technically be run with a single execution statement following it, for clarity's sake, most people use a block even with a single statement.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  b[i] = a[i];
}
```

The semicolon before the execution statement in your code means that the loop runs `a.length` times without doing anything.

You should also look at the [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) operation for array access.